# tor browser crashes every time on mac

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

The Tor Browser ( 6.0.2 ) keeps on crashing on MAC ox ( 10.11.6 ) i can't visit a site for more than 1 minutes before it crashes and have to restart

can anyone help?

Comment: Re-download the browser, restart your computer, and try again.

Comment: thanks for answer i did but nothing change

Comment: Does this still happen with version 6.0.4?

Comment: the same problem. But now I've a newest ver.
So this is one of apples reports: Process: firefox [33279]
Path: /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
Identifier: org.mozilla.tor browser
Version: 6.0.5 (4500.1.1)
Code Type: X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process: ??? [1]
Responsible: firefox [33279]
User ID: 501 Date/Time: 2016-09-17 11:33:20.892 +0300
OS Version: Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1004)
Report Version: 11
Anonymous UUID: 63DB85D8-C0CE-773F-D3B8-862DA5A752F9 Time Awake Since Boot: 150000 seconds System Integrity Protection: enabled Crashed Thread: 4 Socket Thread Exception Type: EXC_BAD_